# Hausdorff distance and Hausdorff dimension

Tags: continuity, hausdorff-distance, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space, $A$, $B$ two compact subsets of $X$ such that the Hausdorff distance $dist_H$ between $A$ and $B$ is small:
$$
dist_H(A, B) \leq \epsilon,
$$
with $\epsilon > 0$.
Does it imply that the Hausdorff dimensions $dim_H A$ and $dim_H B$ are closed to each other ?
In other words, is the Hausdorff dimension continuous with respect to the Hausdorff distance ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple example.  Let $n$ be a positive integer.  Let
$$
A = [0,1]\quad\text{and}\quad B_n = \left\{\frac{k}{n}\;:\;k=0,1,2,\dots,n\right\}
$$
Then $\operatorname{dist}_\mathrm{H}(A,B_n) =\frac{1}{2n}$;
$\dim_H A = 1$; $\dim_H B_n = 0$.

So $\operatorname{dist}_\mathrm{H}(A,B_n) \to 0$ but 
$\dim_H B_n \not\to \dim_H A$.

Comment: Thank you for this nice example.

Answer (score 0):

No. For instance, if $(X,d)$ is locally compact and $K\subseteq X$ is compact, then for all $\varepsilon>0$ there is some relatively compact open set $U$ such that $K\subseteq U\subseteq K_\varepsilon$, and therefore $d_H\left(K,\overline U\right)\le \varepsilon$. However, $\dim_H\overline U$ is larger than the Hausdorff dimension of *some* open ball. And, say, in $\Bbb R^n$ the dimension all balls is $n$, while there are of course subsets of Hausdorff dimension smaller than $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: What if $A$ and $B$ are connected sets?

Comment: @bill Irrelevant. In fact, if $K$ is connected and balls are connected, then $U$ may be chosen to be connected.

Comment: Thank you again. However, we have $\vert diam(A) - diam(B) \vert \leq dist_H(A, B)$. So, are there any other measures or dimensions of $A$ and $B$ whose difference is bounded by the Hausdorff distance? Maybe the topological dimension?

Comment: @bill Topological dimension won't do, because it's still $n$ for the $n$-ball. Others I don't know (which doesn't by any means exclude the possibility).

Comment: Thank you very much; you provide an example in which you assume that $K$ has a small dimension. What can be said if $A$ is a connected compact set with a large topological dimension, and $B$ is closed to $A$ wrt the Hausdorff distance?

Comment: If you read carefully, I don't necessarily assume $K$ to have small dimension. If $K\subseteq \Bbb R^n$, anything goes as long as the dimension is not $n$.

Comment: $(X, d)$ has infinite dimension and is not locally compact. $A$ can have an arbitrarily large dimension.

Comment: The construction I have described does not apply in such a space. ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯